# can I vary sequence of lambda values lasso to compare variable importance?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, feature-selection, lasso, importance

Lasso will do the variable selection, and if I want to know the "variable importance" in the model, does it make sense to adjust the lambda value and get the variables(Features) retained in the different models to see what is dropped and kept? Like, does it make sense to say the variables picked by big lambda-value-model are more important than those who are dropped while present in smaller lambda models?

Comment: Some researchers use a two-step LASSO procedure to screen features in the first step and estimate a prediction model in the second.

Comment: An example of the procedure suggested above is relaxed lasso. See Meinshausen, N. (2007). Relaxed lasso. *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis, 52* (1), 374-393.